# Basic actions in hopper disassembler

Tags: hopper

I have some questions about some hopper disassembler features.

- Is there a way to add a structure definition to the database ? How ?
- Is there a way to assign a type (especially structure or structure pointer) to a local variable ? How exactly ?
- Is there a way to assign a synonym for register and see this synonym in decompilation view ?

Used version of the Hopper is 4.0.35.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Hopper do let you define the types for local variables.

With the focus on a procedure open the inspector and navigate down to the "Local Variables" section. Double click on the variable you want to change and a dialog will appear where you can change the name /and/ set the type for that variable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer from the support (thanks, @Vincent Bénony)

- There is a possibility to add a structure to the database, Modify --> Manage Types.
- There is **no** possibility to assign a type to local variable for now.
- There is a possibility to assign a synonym for register, but it will not be seen in decompilation view.